# Angular doesn't bind data from controller with bindToController

Tags: angularjs

I've been struggling for quite some time with this issue. AngularJS just doesn't bind data if I simply bind it to controller context.
And if I try to change it to simple binding via $scope — everything works.

The trick is with the line that assigns function loadComments — strangely, if I remove it, everything works.

The version of Angular is 1.4.0-beta.5

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('my-app')
.directive 'myComments',
  ->
  directive = 
    restrict: 'E'
    scope: true
    controller: 'CommentsController'
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    bindToController: true
    templateUrl: 'comments.html'
    replace: true

.controller 'CommentsController', () ->
  this.name = 'Comments'

  this.loadComments = ->

// The template is here
section.comments
  header ng-bind='ctrl.name'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that somewhere above the "my-comments" directive on your main page is an `ng-app="my-app"` directive, right?

Comment: Of course, as I said, the rendering via $scope works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the answer — you have to return this explicitly at the end of controller. Haven't found the details, but it looks that depending on the return result the framework decides whether to add it to scope or not.

Comment: I think it's just CoffeeScript returning the last statement in every function, even though you really don't want to return anything from your controller constructor. I tried it out [in a Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LuhaiQnkYmDkOKbxukii?p=preview), and it works when you either return nothing or return the `this.name = "Comments"` part, but fails when you return the `loadComments` function.